# Sheaf cohomology of $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let $\mathbb{P}$ denote the projective space over $\mathbb{C}$. In some lecture notes I found the claim that

> $$ h^0(\mathbb{P}^3, \mathcal{O}(2)) = 10 $$

Do you know why this is the case?

In general, is there any formula which allows to compute $h^a(\mathbb{P}^b, \mathcal{O}(c))$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainly. To find $h^0$: what is the dimension of the vector space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $c$ in $b+1$ variables?

Using for instance the [Stars & Bars method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), one can see that the answer is

$${b+c \choose c}$$

Example: ${3+2 \choose 2}=10$.

As for higher cohomology, see Hartshorne Chapter III, which shows that $h^a(\mathbf P^b, \mathcal O(c))=0$ for $0<a<b$ and *any* $c$. For $h^{b}$, one uses Serre duality to relate it to $h^0$ (of a different line bundle).